# Allowed to request a move?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, etiquette, migration

I asked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/129397/dns-queries-not-using-nscd-for-caching) question on superuser It hasn't gotten what I'd consider to be an actual answer. Can I ask for it to be moved for serverfault? where it might have more luck. I'm not sure that It's more appropriate there, or that it'd be inappropriate there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a valid question for SF to me ( I wouldn't vote to close it)

You should just go ahead and flag it for moderator attention and ask them to move it the provided field.